# Doing Dot notation for Dart Objects?

Tags: dart

I am currently working on a localization class which will be static and accessed in other parts of the application, in dart.

My target goal is to wire up code in a simple fashion:

```
Localization.MY_STRING
```

and then it will return: `"my string"`

At first, I was thinking that everything in localization would be static and publicly available, but writing everything out:

```
static String MY_STRING = "my string";
```

seems tedious, plus i was wanting it to be in a Map, sort of like JSON files:

```
{
  MY_STRING: "my string"
}
```

Is there a simple way to create a static map so i can accomplish my goals?

I was thinking i might be able to override the `.` by maybe defining it:

```
String .operator (String value){ 
  return map[value]?map[value]:"";
}
```

in a similar fashion to defining `<=operator` in classes.

Has anyone else tried anything like this?  Im thinking I might for the timing being storing everything in a JSON file, and then just reading that information in to some class.

Comment: Im thinking that I will actually use An interpretor to auto general this script file.

Comment: You might have a look at the `intl` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override the `.` operator. Only a limited set of operators can be overloaded.

If you create the fields outside a class, you don't need `static`. You can import the library with a prefix to get the same syntax as static field access.

Comment: I created a dart file that will do everything i need for localization by reading in a JSON file, then outputting a dart file which can be referenced.  This ending dart file is then usable by the project as long as it is executed prior to running the the web application.  That way, It dynamically creates a large class file of statics to allow me to do `Localization.MY_STRING`

Comment: You still might have a look at the `intl` package. It takes care of a few additional things. Support for a file format that's supported by Google translate, lazy loading of language files, pluralization, ... It's quite a while I had a closer look and don't remember all details.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking to take a look at `intl` but soemone above me said no.  So, i am just creating something as a holdover until higher determines how they are doing things.

Comment: It is a design decision to have to use the ['strKey'] instead of the dot notation. Do you have any idea why they took that decision instead of being closer to js ?

Comment: Because `strKey` is not a property of an object, it's just a key of a collection. A big difference is, that in Dart a Map key doesn't need to be a String.